# Issue with onIncomingCall PJSIP Function

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, console-application

**Description**
"I'm facing an issue with my code where the on incoming call function doesn't seem to be working as expected. Can you provide guidance on how to effectively test if this function is working correctly?"

**Environment**

- Programming language: [C#]
- Framework or library: [pjsip-pjsua2-cs]
- Version numbers: [2.10.1]

  ```
    static async Task Main()
    {
        try
        {
            #region  Initialize PJSIP
            Endpoint ep = new Endpoint();
            ep.libCreate();
            EpConfig epConfig = new EpConfig();
            ep.libInit(epConfig);
            TransportConfig transportConfig = new TransportConfig();
            transportConfig.port = 5060; 

            // Create a TCP transport with your SIP server settings
            TransportConfig tcfg = new TransportConfig();
            tcfg.port = 5060;
            ep.transportCreate(pjsip_transport_type_e.PJSIP_TRANSPORT_UDP,
                       tcfg);
            ep.transportCreate(pjsip_transport_type_e.PJSIP_TRANSPORT_TCP,
                       tcfg);
            #endregion
            #region Configure a SIP account
            // Load your SIP settings from configuration
            SipSettings config = LoadSipSettingsFromConfiguration();

            // Create and configure a SIP account
            AccountConfig accCfg = CreateSipAccountConfig(config);
            Account acc = new Account();
            acc.create(accCfg);
            #endregion


            Console.WriteLine("SIP account created. Press Enter to exit.");
            Console.ReadLine();
            ep.Dispose();
            accCfg.Dispose();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Error: " + ex.Message);
        }
    }
  ```

```
    #region onIncomingCall function
        public override void onIncomingCall(OnIncomingCallParam prm)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Incoming call received.");

            // Handle the incoming call here, e.g., answer the call
            MyCall call = new MyCall(this, prm.callId);
            CallOpParam callOpParam = new CallOpParam(true);
            call.answer(callOpParam);
            // Now, integrate Direct Line bot conversation logic here
            HandleBotConversation(call);
        }
```

Implement event handlers to manage incoming calls and audio streams

Answer (score 0):

This function is working correctly

add the line a code
**call.makeCall("Enter the receiver Sip address", prm);**

```
static async Task Main()
{
  try
  {
      #region  Initialize PJSIP
      Endpoint ep = new Endpoint();
      ep.libCreate();
      EpConfig epConfig = new EpConfig();
      ep.libInit(epConfig);
      TransportConfig transportConfig = new TransportConfig();
      transportConfig.port = 5060; 

      // Create a TCP transport with your SIP server settings
      TransportConfig tcfg = new TransportConfig();
      tcfg.port = 5060;
      ep.transportCreate(pjsip_transport_type_e.PJSIP_TRANSPORT_UDP,
                 tcfg);
      ep.transportCreate(pjsip_transport_type_e.PJSIP_TRANSPORT_TCP,
                 tcfg);
      ep.libStart();
      #endregion
      #region Configure a SIP account
      // Load your SIP settings from configuration
      SipSettings config = LoadSipSettingsFromConfiguration();

      // Create and configure a SIP account
     AccountConfig accCfg = new AccountConfig();
            accCfg.idUri = "Your Sip address";
            accCfg.regConfig.registrarUri = "Your Domain";
            accCfg.sipConfig.authCreds.Add(
                new AuthCredInfo("digest", "*", "Username", 0, "Password"));
            MyAccount acc = new MyAccount();
            acc.create(accCfg);
      #endregion

       // Make a call (assuming you have a valid destination URI)
            CallOpParam prm = new CallOpParam(true);
            Call call = new Call(acc, -1);
            call.makeCall("Enter the receiver Sip address", prm);
      Console.WriteLine("SIP account created. Press Enter to exit.");
      Console.ReadLine();
      ep.Dispose();
      accCfg.Dispose();
  }
  catch (Exception ex)
  {
      Console.WriteLine("Error: " + ex.Message);
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**